# How can I convert the string (position) to int?

Tags: c#

I get compiling error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

```
{
    public Transform player;
    public Text scoreText;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        int score = player.position.z.ToString("0");
        scoreText.text = score.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line of code gives the error ?

Comment: `int.Parse(player.position.z.ToString("0"))` or use `TryParse`. But why change it to int if you need it as a string?

Comment: Oh, sorry forgot to mention that, the following line "  int score = player.position.z.ToString("0");"

Comment: `ToString`surely returns a `string`, not an `int`. I suppose you can completely omit your `score`-variable and just use `scoreText.text = player.position.z.ToString("0");`.

Comment: `z` is a float, so you're doing a lot of unnecessary work by making it into a string and then trying to convert it to an integer. You can cast it to an int like this `int score = (int)player.position.z;`

Comment: @CodingYoshi Im trying to create a score system which saves the highest score I have reached as z position moves on. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `int score = Integer.parseInt( player.position.z.ToString("0") );`

Answer (score 0):

`player.position.z` is a `float` (see the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) of a `Vector3`). So now you are trying to convert this `float` to an `int`, but you are doing this with the `toString()` method, which converts the `float` to a `string`. This does not work, because you cannot set the value of a `int`, to one of a `string`.

You can convert the float to an int by casting:

```
int score = (int) player.position.z;
```

Or by using the rounding methods from Unity ([documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.RoundToInt.html)):

```
int score = Mathf.RoundToInt(player.position.z)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using Unity. Here `z` is a float. What it looks like you're trying to do is taking that float, converting it to a string. Then converting it to an int and then converting it to a string again.

Since what you need is a string, you can go directly from the float to a string like this:

```
{
    public Transform player;
    public Text scoreText;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        scoreText.text = player.position.z.ToString("0");
    }
}
```